# Multiple ajax requests not working after a while

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have my page which loads live stock data from server continuously (every second)  making request to a php file named **data.php**. Also I have a Ganns square of 9 calculator that passes value to a PHP file (**getdata.php**) using ajax through a OnKeyUp function of a textbox and returns some output.

The issue is-
As the page loads both work perfectly. Live data as well as calculator can be used. But after a while the calculator doesn't work. On writing value into the textbox the request must be processed and value must be returned through ajax call, but it doesn't happen.

**Live Stock data code (refreshes every sec):**

```
<script>
            function showPort(t)
            {
            var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                document.getElementById("portfo").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
              }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","data.php",true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            setTimeout(showPort,t);
            }
          </script>
```

It runs using on page load-

```
<body onload="JavaScript:showPort(2000);">
```

**Ganns square calculator code which runs onkeyup event of textbox:**

```
<script>
            function showData(str)
            {
            if (str.length==0)
              {
              document.getElementById("txtData").innerHTML="";
              return;
              }
            var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                document.getElementById("txtData").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
              }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata.php?a="+str,false);
            xmlhttp.send();
            }
          </script>
```

Runs onKeyUp event of textbox-

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Last traded Price" name="str" onKeyUp="showData(this.value)">
```

I tried searching for similar questions but did not get my answer. Thus, posting this issue as a new question here.

Comment: Can't you use jQuery? I saw that you have that in the tags, but there's nothing in the code! :)

Comment: I'm not comfortable with JQuery. But If there is an easy way to do it with JQuery then I'm ready to go with that. :)

Comment: @ChandanJah Yes mate. It will be easier!

Comment: Then help me with that buddy.
I would try doing that. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first script:

```
function showPort(t)
{
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("portfo").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","data.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    setTimeout(showPort,t);
}
```

Can be converted this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $.get("data.php", function(data){
            $("#portfo").html(data);
        });
    }, 2000);
});
```

And the next one:

```
function showData(str)
{
    if (str.length==0)
    {
        document.getElementById("txtData").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("txtData").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata.php?a="+str,false);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
function showData(str)
{
    if (str.length==0)
    {
        $("#txtData").html("");
        return;
    }
    $.get("getdata.php?a="+str, function(data){
        $("#txtData").html(data);
    });
}
```

Can you please try executing the above code and see if it works? Don't forget to include jQuery this way:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
```

Comment: So I do not need to call the function on page load, ri8??

Comment: So, I tried the code u have given. the second one works perfectly but the first set of code doesn't seem to work. It does not output anything. the area is left blank.
I'll cross my code again and revert back here soon.

Comment: @ChandanJha Sure... Waiting.. :)

Comment: the first set of code doesn't seem to work. Does not return any data.

Comment: in data.php I have two echo? is that a problem. Coz it was working fine earlier. :)

Comment: Try removing it and putting it back?

Comment: Does not work!
Tried removing all the echo and just printing a single text. But still  outputs a blank space. :( So, I tried going back to my code. And that one's still running. It means there's nothing wrong with data.php

Comment: So, got it working.
You made a very small mistake buddy!
setInterval(code,delay) <-- must be this way
We used it the other way around. that made it ineffective.. :D
So, thanks a lot @PraveenKumar :)
Issue resolved... ;)